# Git / Eclipse line ending flipping

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I've got a peculiar line ending git commit versioning problem with one of the developers on my team. Similar to many other posts, the line endings are all being changed from one style to another (CRLF to LF or vice versa) and the commit history doesn't highlight the actual change, since every single line as been altered. What's different about my problem, is that there's no consistency about which files this happens with and the direction that the flip happens.

I've got scenarios when a unix style file was flipped to a windows style, and when windows styles have been flipped to unix. At first I assumed 1 person's machine was flipping in one direction and another flipping it back, but to my astonishment, the same user is sometimes flipping files in either direction.  Also, it doesn't do this every time.  I'd say it decides to do this to about 1/4 of the files.

From what I can see, this developer is using the same exact setup as everyone else on the team:

Running Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 on Windows 7
The eclipse preferences General->Workspace: "New text file line delimeter" is set to "Default (Windows)"
Everyone has core.autocrlf set to true in their .git/config file
Commiting files with EGit 4.0.3
We've all got the latest version of git installed 2.6.x
We're using bitbucket as our git hosting service if that makes a difference.

If anyone has any ideas about anything else I can try it'd be appreciated. Something weird about our repo I discovered is that about half the files in our repository use Unix (LF) style line endings and the other half windows (CRLF).  It's been the case for a while apparently and hasn't caused any issues because everyone else's setup has properly kept the same line endings that the file had used.

Comment: Do you have a `.gitattributes`?  If so, what does it say?  If not, why not?

Comment: No we don't.  I was thinking of adding one to attempt to fix this.

Comment: Check out this answer http://superuser.com/questions/882691/atlassian-sourcetree-how-to-change-line-endings-globally/882929#882929